# Dropdown menu is not being shown

Tags: html, css

**I cannot find out why the dropdown menu does not work. I am completely new in web dev**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHJWi.png)

Comment: [Please include code as text not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added bootstrap CDN link like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Check this link for navbar with dropdown menu:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

Post your html and css here. I can see only html code in image

Answer (score 0):

Make the dropdown-menu class div tag a ul tag and all the links that need to be dropdown-items in li tags. That should work I guess.

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Categories
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.